# Is there an OCaml '@@' operator, and what does it mean?

Tags: ocaml

I'm an OCaml n00b and trying to make sense of the following source file:

https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/bap_disasm/bap_disasm_shingled.ml

On line 46 there is the following code:

```
let static_successors gmin gmax lmem insn =
  let fall_through =
    if not (is_exec_ok gmin gmax lmem) then [None, `Fall]
    else
      let i = Word.((Memory.min_addr lmem) ++ (Memory.length lmem)) in      
      [Some i, `Fall] in
  if (Insn.may_affect_control_flow insn) then (
    let targets = (Insn.bil insn |> dests_of_bil) in
    if (not @@ Insn.is_unconditional_jump insn) then
      List.append fall_through targets
    else
      targets
  ) else fall_through
```

I'm getting the gist of most of this function, but the `if (not @@ Insn.is_unconditional_jump insn` part is stumping me. I can't seem to find a reference for the `@@` operator/function; it seems to be applying the function to the instance `insn` somehow.

So, is `@@` a built-in operator, if so what does it do? If not, how would I find the declaration for the operator/function, so I can hunt it down and figure it out?

Comment: Its evaluating the expression to the right for you. Same as if you just used (). example: print_endline (String.lower "Hello") is the same as print_endline @@ String.lower "hello". you can get the signature in utop or plain ocaml repl,   ( @@ );;
- : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This operator was introduced in `Pervasives` (the "always opened" module) in 4.01.

Basically, it is of type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`. So `f @@ x` is equivalent to `f x`.

The good thing is its associativity and precedence.

In this specific case, `not @@ Insn.is_unconditional_jump insn` is exactly the same as `not (Insn.is_unconditional_jump insn)`.

It is declared as an internal primitive, so that would not help you much, but you can see the informations about it in the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL%28@@%29).

Comment: I see, this is like Haskell's `$`, so that it just strongly controls the precedence of function application.